# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' while trying to print a quoted line in Shell bash

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I want to print the following line but I need this line:

```
export PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc; /local/Miniconda3/bin/python3 scripts/DNAscan.py ${var}
```

to be quoted. I used \" in order to achieve that but I'm getting this error:

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

This is the command:

```
"${comand} bash -c  \"export PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc; /local/Miniconda3/bin/python3 scripts/DNAscan.py ${var}\""
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with `export PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc`?  The export command produces no output, so the redirection doesn't really do anything.

Comment: It feels as if you just want to set PATH for the invocation of `scripts/DNSscan.py`.  If you are trying to insert a line in your .bashrc, you should do that manually.  Automatically appending to .bashrc leads to 10,000 line startup files.  Don't do that.

Comment: I want to use that command as a command to execute in a Docker container. I need it to be in string format

Comment: I've been forced to set the path again because when I run conda from outside the docker container it doesn't find it. Instead, if I run a command that calls Conda inside the container it works perfectly. I don't understand the nature of the problem

Comment: You need the PATH to be set for a particular command, but you do not need it in the .bashrc.  Getting it in the .bashrc is one way to solve the problem, but this is (probably) not the best way to get it there.  You could add it earlier in the docker file, or change the template, but probably you want to set the environment in the docker file.  More details are needed.

Comment: I add it earlier in the dockerfile and it works perfectlly if i run any command that involve conda. The thing is if I run the same command outside the container (with exec) it seems that it doesn't find the appropriate path.

Comment: If i run `which conda` outside the container i receive nothing but if I run it inside the container it returns me the appropriate path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going wrong with your command but would like to note that the variables 'comand' and 'var' are both being resolved, if this was not your intention consider using single quotes ' ' or escaping the '$' signs in your string with backslashes '\'.